# Ionic 2 with Reveal.js presentation inside

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, reveal.js

I'm working in a Reveal.js presentation, for future needs I'm wrapping it around an Ionic 2 app.

First approach is working fine, what I've done is a simple sidemenu template with a page that loads the Reveal.js presentation.

At first it seems to work fine, but:

**issue**: First time I open the Reveal.js page, it loads ok, but If I'm loading another page, and then returning to it, it doesn't load the presentation.

Example:
https://github.com/xanisu/ionic2-reveal.js

> reveal.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as Reveal from 'reveal.js/js/reveal';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-reveal',
  templateUrl: 'reveal.html'
})

export class RevealPage {

 reveal : any;
 loaded : boolean = false;


onstructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

 }
ngOnInit() { 
    console.log("ngOnInit!");
    this.reveal = Reveal;
    this.loadSlides();
}

loadSlides() {

    //this function is intended to load all dinamic content for slides (json, bbdd, webservice....)

     this.revealInit(); 
}
ionViewDidLeave() {
    this.loaded = false;
}
revealInit() {
    this.reveal.addEventListener( 'ready', ( event ) => {
        this.loaded = true;
    });

    let revealOptions = {
        controls: true,
        progress: true,
        slideNumber: false,
        history: false,
        keyboard: true,
        overview: true,
        center: true,
        touch: true,
        loop: false,
        rtl: false,
        shuffle: false,
        fragments: true,
        embedded: false,
        help: true,
        showNotes: false,
        autoSlide: 0,
        autoSlideStoppable: true,
        autoSlideMethod: Reveal.navigateNext,
        mouseWheel: false,
        hideAddressBar: true,
        previewLinks: false,
        transition: 'slide', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom 
        transitionSpeed: 'default', // default/fast/slow 
        backgroundTransition: 'fade', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom 
        viewDistance: 3,
        parallaxBackgroundImage: '', // e.g. "'https://s3.amazonaws.com/hakim-static/reveal-js/reveal-parallax-1.jpg'" 
        parallaxBackgroundSize: '', // CSS syntax, e.g. "2100px 900px" 
        parallaxBackgroundHorizontal: null,
        parallaxBackgroundVertical: null

    };

    this.reveal.initialize(revealOptions);       
}
}
```

> reveal.html

```
<div class="reveal">
    <div class="slides">
        <section>Single Horizontal Slide 1</section>
        <section>
            <section>Vertical Slide 2.1</section>
            <section>Vertical Slide 2.2</section>
        </section>
        <section>Single Horizontal Slide 3</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is code you are using in your component to call reveal.js, you might be hooking into the wrong life cycle event. If it is in `ionViewDidLoad` a `pop` navigation will not fire the code again as it takes a cached version

Comment: It is inside `ngOnInit()` event call. It can be checked in the reveal.ts file in github repo [link](https://github.com/xanisu/ionic2-reveal.js/blob/master/src/pages/reveal/reveal.ts)

Comment: Did you get the answer? Actually I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, in your Reveal.js version (3.5.0) you can only use the `Reveal.initialize()` once. [This github feature request](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/1732) is the only info I could find about it.

In the 4.0.0 Reveal.js version there is a new feature called [Multiple Presentations](https://revealjs.com/initialization/#multiple-presentations) so now you can create multiple instances of the Reveal class and initialize a new one each time you enter the page.

Even though we don't want to have multiple presentations side to side, this solved my problem when revisiting the same page won't load the Reveal slides again.

A brief example of how you can store your `<div class="reveal presentation">...</div>` in a new instance of Reveal could be something like this:

```
ngOnInit() { 
    console.log("ngOnInit!");
    let presentation = new Reveal(document.querySelector('.presentation'));
    presentation.initialize();
}
```